# Linearly independent (3 vectors)

Tags: vectors

3 vectors $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^3$ are linearly independent, if the equation system

$$c_1 a + c_2 b + c_3 c = 0$$

is only solved by $c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = 0$.
This is equivalent to the fact that I consider the 3 vectors as a matrix ? so the 3 vectors are linearly independent exactly when the determinant of the matrix is different from zero?

Is this true?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is a part of the Invertible Matrix Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true. The matrix $(a b c)$ is invertible if and only if its determinant is nonzero and if and only if its rank is $3$ which is the case if and only if $\{a,b,c\}$ is linearly independent

Comment: You're welcome.